# Why do I only get ethernet connection through the right usb port and why does it stop working if I unplug and replug?

Tags: usb, ethernet

I've been trying to use a usb > ethernet adapter to get a connection and have the following issue (Mid 2014 Macbook Pro, 13", BigSur 11.2.2):

1. Only the right side usb port works in terms of ethernet connection, left gets nothing
2. When I connected the Macbook right side usb, the first time I got an ethernet signal.
3. I then unplugged and tried again - no signal (no signal at any point through the left side usb port)
4. I restarted my Macbook, reset SMC and PRAM
5. Able to connect through ethernet on right side usb port only (left nothing), but as above, only works once. If I unplug and try again, no connection.
6. I can use other usb devices on both sides no problem - usb memory stick, mouse etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1. What brand of adapter do you have? Apple, or third party? 2. Do you have another ethernet adapter and/or computer to try? 3. Use the `Hardware > USB` section of the *System Information* app (`Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report`) to check for the presence of the dongle when it **is** working. (Also click on the device and take a screenshot of the report for later comparison.) Then unplug the dongle, plug it back in, confirm that it is **not** working, press Command+R to reload the report, and see if the device is still present. Please amend your question with answers to these.